# Query to merge values into record from related table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table "A" as:

```
ID_A Name  ID_B 
1    John  1
2    Mary  2
3    John  2
4    Mary  1
5    Peter 1
```

And a table "B":

```
ID_B  Keys
1     Mousse
2     Banana
```

I want to create one table with this result:

```
ID_B Keys    Name1 Name2 Name3
1    Mousse  John  Mary  Peter
2    Banana  Mary  John  Null
```

Is there any query to build this?

Thanks

Comment: Which database? sql-query-store is not an RDBMS, do you mean MS-SqlServer

Comment: PostgresSQL. I have changed the tag

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't do precisely what you describe, which is an indeterminate number of columns.  I don't know of a way to do that with just SQL.

That said, PostgreSQL has great array support, and this gets you 90% of the way there.

```
select
  b.id_b, array_agg (a.name) as names
from
  b
  join a on
    b.id_b = a.id_b
group by
  b.id_b
```

You can even mix it up and do things like:

```
array_agg (a.name order by a.id_a)
```

or

```
array_agg (distinct a.name)
```